# ember 2.0 nested dynamic templates renders the wrong template

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Others have posted similar problems on stackoverflow, but no answers yet...

My first dynamic route works. I have a nested dynamic route inside the first dynamic route, but the template of that nested route is never displayed.

This route works (the post.hbs is displayed):

```
#/home/post/29
```

But for this route:

```
#/home/post/29/comment/123
```

I expect the comment.hbs to display, but the post.hbs is still displayed.

My router looks like:

```
this.route('home', { path: '/home'}, function() {
    this.route('post', {path: "/post/:post_id"}, function() {
        this.route('comment', {path: "/comment/:comment_id"}, function() {
        ....
```

In my post.hbs I have this:

```
<div {{action 'doNavigateToComment' comment}}>
```

In my route\home\post.js I have:

```
doNavigateToComment(comment_id) {
  this.transitionTo('home.post.comment', this.get('postId'), comment_id);
}
```

My filestructure looks like this:

```
\routes
  home.js
  \home
    post.js
    \post
      comment.js
\templates
  \home
    index.hbs
    post.hbs
    post\
      comment.hbs
```

Tracing is turned on in the console, but it shows no error.

I am using ember 1.13.5 (which shall behave like ember 2.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `{{outlet}}` in your `post.hbs` to render inside the `comment.hbs`.

Edit:
Due your requirement of having `post` replaced by `comment` you could use one of these options:
1) Edit your router so `comment` won't be nested to `post` but nested to `home`:

```
this.route('home', { path: '/home'}, function() {
    this.route('post', {path: "/post/:post_id"}, function() {});
    this.route('comment', {path: "/comment/:comment_id"}, function() {});
    ....
```

2) Change your `post.hbs` to behave as you want:

```
{{#if pathIsForPosts}}
    ...
{{else}}
    {{outlet}}
{{/if}}
```

`pathIsForPosts` could be a computed property that analyses the `path` and return `true` or `false` if it's a path for posts or comments.

Comment: Does that apply to my case?. I have `{{outlet}}` in `application.hbs` and my `post.hbs` shall be completely replaced by `comment.hbs`

Comment: Checking the documentation of [emberjs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes), I think you can do the option 2 just by adding a `index.hbs` to the post route and having only `{{outlet}}` in post. This way, `index`will be rendered when accessing `home/post/id` and `comment` will be rendered when accessing `home/post/id/comment/id`.

Comment: That did it! Thanx! I do now understand it is a big difference between using `index.hbs` and not. (I did use option 2 with `index.hbs` as outlined in your comment)